# OctoberCMS change backend menu organization

Tags: menu, backend, octobercms

I want to change OctoberCMS backend menu organization.
Example:
I want to move from sidebar of Rainlab Plugin Static Pages - Menus to OctoberCMS CMS SideBar or it can be possible to add Rainlab Plugin Static Pages - Menus to main menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your plugin.php file with registerNavigation function. For example this code define top menu and sidebar menu:

```
return [
        'title' => [
            'label' => 'title',
            'url' => Backend::url('...'),
            'icon' => 'icon-cube',
            'permissions' => ['access.*'],
            'order' => 501,

            'sideMenu' => [
                'title' => [
                    'label' => '....',
                    'url' => Backend::url('....'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-slack',
                    'permissions' => ['access'],
                    'order' => 500,
                ],
```

Also in your controller you must define this:

```
BackendMenu::setContext('Author.Plugin Name', 'plugin', 'model');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be really obvious but I'll still say it just to be sure. If you are looking at changing the appearance or location of Backend Menu Items provided by plugins you did not author, don't make any changes to those files yourself. You would just loose all such custom changes everytime you update that plugin.

A better idea would be to create your own plugin that uses the 3rd-party plugin as a dependency and then make required changes to this new plugin.

Example Case: You wish to alter the display of the RainLab.User plugin backend menu item.

Create a new plugin and name it as needed. For ex: Acme.UserExtension.
Now in the `plugin.php` file of this new plugin you can add a dependency on the RainLab.User plugin and then hide it's menu item like so:

```
public $require = ['RainLab.User'];

public function boot()
{
    /** Add a side-menu item */
    Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function($manager) {
        $manager->addSideMenuItem('RainLab.User', 'user', [
            'payments' => [
                'label' => '...'
            ]
        ]);
    });

    /** Add a custom main-menu item */
    Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function($manager) {
        $manager->addMainMenuItem('Acme.UserExtension', 'user');
    });

    /** Remove the original main-menu item */
    Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function($manager) {
        $manager->removeMainMenuItem('RainLab.User', 'user');
    });

}
```

As you can see you can completely remove a menu item for a plugin you dont own if you want. You could just extend it like shown above and just use the `registerNavigation()` method to do what you need for this *extension* plugin. You might have to replicate some of the menu items you do want to retain from the original parent plugin but now you have the ability to add some of your own or remove the items you don't need.

More details on how you can do this are here -> http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#extending-backend-menu

Hopefully this isn't too convoluted and helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

While extending standard October backend controllers is very easy and described in documentation (mentioned in answers above), manipulations with Static Pages by RainLab are more complicated as "side navigation" (tabs) is handled with JavaScript. It's not possible to add a new item to this plugin navigation through the methods from the October CMS docs or to add "menu" sidemenu item to another plugin. With standard extend it's possible to show only one tab (you were asking about menu) but this won't set it as default and "pages" will still be shown as default.

If you are using only Static Menu my solution is to rename top menu Pages -> Menus and hide all tabs except "menu" with permissions (they will still be visible for admin but at least won't confuse backend editor). Will be happy if someone will share a better solution.

The code to place in your custom plugin, in boot() + don't forget to set permissions while creating a backend user for the client.

```
// Rename rainlab.menu pages to menu
Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function($manager) 
{ 
  $manager->addMainMenuItems('RainLab.Pages', [
    'pages' => [
      'label' => 'Menu',
      'url'   => Backend::url('rainlab/pages'),
      'icon'  => 'icon-align-justify',
      'sideMenu' => [
        'menus' => [
          'label' => 'rainlab.pages::lang.menu.menu_label',
          'icon'  => 'icon-sitemap',
          'url'   => 'javascript:;',
          'attributes'  => ['data-menu-item'=>'menus'],
          'permissions' => ['rainlab.pages.manage_menus']
        ],
      ]
    ],
  ]);
});
```